# How to reset value in map of maps

Tags: dictionary, go

Here's my code

```
{
    saruman := map[string]int{
     "power": 150,
     "skills": 200,
     "knowledge": 380,
    }

    gandalf := map[string]int{
     "power": 180,
     "skills": 210,
     "knowledge": 240,
    }

    wizards := make(map[string]interface{})
    wizards["saruman"] = saruman
    wizards["gandalf"] = gandalf

    fmt.Println(wizards)
    //OK map[gandalf:map[knowledge:240 power:180 skills:210] saruman:map[knowledge:380 power:150 skills:200]]

    //change gandalf property
    wizards["gandalf"]["knowledge"] = 310

    fmt.Println(wizards)
}
```

In the last line, we get:

> NOK invalid operation: wizards["gandalf"]["knowledge"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `["key"]` to access a structure that golang does not know about. Because it is an `interface{}` the value behind gandalf could be anything.

```
    wizards["gandalf"] = map[string]int{
         "knowledge": 310,
    }
```

You have to specify the type of data you are interacting with.

Playground: https://goplay.tools/snippet/O62ara8JbUv

Comment: The above solution will replace the initial value of gandalf with the new value.
To just update the value of knowledge attribute for gandalf, retrieve the inital value of gandalf with type casting and then update the value of gandalf's attribute.

Playground link [here](https://go.dev/play/p/Jyl-_VipDgN)

Answer (score 0):

Need to cast it.

```
{
    saruman := map[string]int{
        "power":     150,
        "skills":    200,
        "knowledge": 380,
    }

    gandalf := map[string]int{
        "power":     180,
        "skills":    210,
        "knowledge": 240,
    }

    wizards := make(map[string]interface{})
    wizards["saruman"] = saruman
    wizards["gandalf"] = gandalf

    fmt.Println(wizards)
    //OK map[gandalf:map[knowledge:240 power:180 skills:210] saruman:map[knowledge:380 power:150 skills:200]]

    //change gandalf property
    wizards["gandalf"].(map[string]int)["knowledge"] = 10
    fmt.Println(wizards)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easier way:
one line code

```
wizards["gandalf"].(map[string]int)["knowledge"] = 110
```

Full example:

```
saruman := map[string]int{
    "power":     150,
    "skills":    200,
    "knowledge": 380,
}
gandalf := map[string]int{
    "power":     180,
    "skills":    210,
    "knowledge": 240,
}

wizards := make(map[string]interface{})
wizards["saruman"] = saruman
wizards["gandalf"] = gandalf

// fmt.Println(wizards)
// OK map[gandalf:map[knowledge:240 power:180 skills:210] saruman:map[knowledge:380 power:150 skills:200]]

// change gandalf property

wizards["gandalf"].(map[string]int)["knowledge"] = 110
fmt.Println(wizards["gandalf"].(map[string]int)["knowledge"])
```